# Prostration and attachment to rites and rituals

Tags: ethics, prostration

Why isn't prostration considered as a rite or a ritual in the sense of *silabbata paramasa* (one of the fetters that had to be abandoned to become a stream-enterer)?

I wonder how this practice can contribute to insight especially when prostration is done mechanically (as practiced around Buddhist pagodas in Birma; Sri Lanka and Thailand)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I wonder how this practice can contribute to insight especially when prostration is done mechanically (as practiced around Buddhist pagodas in Birma; Sri Lanka and Thailand)?**

Prostrations is done to Revere.

Reverence is an act of merit->Merit brings happiness->Happiness brings Tranquility (Samadhi)->Samadhi brings Insight.

Mind influences the Body, but the body also influences the mind.We can feel happy and smile or we can smile **then** feel happy.The body has a huge impact on the mind.When we stand up straight we tend to feel more confident.

It is possible to do prostration mechanically but it will leave an imprint in your mind and psyche to not behave in a way that shows irreverence.For example,I had a habit of saying a prayer mechanically before dinner,and even when i went to someone else's house and was mindless for most of the day by the time it was dinner time i'd kind of snap out of it and became mindful of the food and say a quick prayer for it.So it's like a force of habit.In this case a good habit.

Answer (score 5):

Preforming a ceremonial act isn't the same thing as clinging to rites and rituals. Clinging to rites and rituals specifically means that you think that some ceremonial action has some sort of power in it that can take you to enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

Any right or ritual does make Sankara / Karma positive or negative. Eradicating Sankara is the way out of misery hence any practice which does not eradicate Sankara is not conducive to get out of misery.

You should understand the formation of Sankara and eradicate it. Formation of Sankara is linked to sensations. When it passes away subtle sensations arise. Likewise you can see rights and rituals cause formations.

But until you get there some attachments to keep you on track and strengthen your faith is no harm.

Comment: This answer assumes that eradicating Sankara is the only way out of misery.